# Android highlight one item in RecyclerView

Tags: android

I readed few questions on stackoverflow about highlight of items in `RecyclerView` but I couldn't achieve anything but my problem should be easier because I only want to have highlighted only one item. I succeed to make something work but it highlights the item that is recycled too.

```
    musicList.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(getApplicationContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, final int position) {

                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(40,100,100,230));
                }
            })
    );
```

And my adapter looks like this:

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private String[] mDataset;

```
// Provide a reference to the views for each data item
// Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
// you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public TextView mTextView;
    public ImageView mp3Icon;
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mp3Icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iconMp3);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(musicPlayer.conv.toPixels(25), musicPlayer.conv.toPixels(30));
        params.setMargins(10,20,20,10);
        mp3Icon.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

}

// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.text_layout, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;

}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);

}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.length;
}
```

}

And also my click listener class:

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildPosition(childView));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) { }
}
```

Also my second attempt was to set in `onBindViewHolder`:

```
if(selectedItem == position){
    holder.mTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(40, 100, 100, 230));
}
```

and when I was clickking on an item in the list I call a method and set the selected item selected but I have the same problem, two items are selected instead of one.

Comment: Did you set the selectedItem = position in the listener when you click on the recycler view item? Because from what I see, since you only require one item highlighted, it should work by checking in the onBindViewHolder the position against the selectedItem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### use this pattern:

- add to adapter method:

> ```
> /**
>  * disable row
>  */
> public void disableRow(int index) {
>     /** 
>      *clear array of disabled rows 
>      * - remove it if u wanna disable more than one row at once 
>      */
>     mDisabledRows.clear();
>     /** add disabled row to array */
>     mDisabledRows.add(index);
>     /** refresh view to show background changes - > call getView */
>     notifyDataSetChanged();   // for my purpose 
> }
> ```

- declare field

> ```
> /** list of disabled rows */
> private ArrayList<Integer> mDisabledRows;
> ```

- initialize field in constructor

> ```
> /** initialize disabled row array */
> mDisabledRows = new ArrayList<>();
> ```

- in method where u get view (for example in onBindViewHolder) use condition to check if your item is disabled

> ```
> /** check if row is disabled */
>   if (mDisabledRows.contains(position)) { 
>        // do somthing to highlight //
>   } else {
>      // do something to un-highlight */
>   }
> ```

- in code use  (as in your case  for CARD)

> ```
> Adapter.disableRow(position)
> ```

**EXPLANATION:**

Adapter will hold array of selected items and tracks changes on given conditions then specific view will be returned

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset the color if it is not selected.

```
if(selectedItem == position){
    holder.mTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(40, 100, 100, 230));
}
else{
    holder.mTextView.setBackgroundColor(defaultColor);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Simple 4 steps to achieve this!

- keep a global variable in adapter to keep track of clicked position.
- create a drawable of selectable with `android:state_activated` states.
- set this drawable as background of view (maybe in your custom row)
- set a view's `isActivated` property.

#### How to do?

- declare global variable

```kotlin
 private var clickedPos: Int = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION // or any other default int
```

- create a selectable

```xml
<!-- file name: bg_selector -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_activated="true">
     <shape
         android:shape="rectangle">

         <corners
             android:radius="4dp"/>
         <stroke
             android:width="@dimen/layout_border_width"
             android:color="@color/gray"/>
     </shape>
 </item>

 <item android:state_activated="false">
     <shape
         android:shape="rectangle">

         <corners
             android:radius="4dp"/>
         <stroke
             android:width="@dimen/layout_border_width"
             android:color="@color/white"/>
     </shape>
 </item>
</selector>
```

- set background in xml(not recycler view, but your custom row xml's view )

```xml
android:background="@drawable/bg_selector"
```

- handle click and keep clicked position in adapter

```kotlin
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
     // other lines

     holder.view.isActivated = position == clickedPos
     holder.view.setOnClickListener {
         clickedPos = position
         notifyDataSetChanged() // Important to call and it notifies of everything
     }
 }
```